# Update multiple contacts with different phone type in Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have some issues when updating phone number for contacts of different phone type. I need to add prefix xxx with all the numbers. For example: "Paul" have Mobile: 42342397908, Home: 3453459534, Work: 4345436533, Other: 3253454354, Other: 3465465464, Mobile: 34564654654. The update is working but when it saves it is like this. Mobile: xxx42342397908, Home: xxx3453459534, Work: xxx4345436533, Other: xx3253454354, Other: xx3253454354, Mobile: xxx42342397908. It overrides the one which have same phone type with the same phone number. please see below my update function and help me.

```
 private void updateContact(String name, String phone,String id, String type) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + 
                    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";

        String[] params = null;
        /*
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builderPhone = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?"+" AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?" + " AND "+Phone.TYPE+"=?",  
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(id), Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(phoneType)});
        */   
        if (Integer.valueOf(type) == Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
        {
        params = new String[] {name,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};
        }
        else if (Integer.valueOf(type) == Phone.TYPE_HOME)
        {
            params = new String[] {name,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)};
            }
        else if (Integer.valueOf(type) == Phone.TYPE_WORK)
        {
            params = new String[] {name,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)};
            }
        else if (Integer.valueOf(type) == Phone.TYPE_OTHER)
        {
            params = new String[] {name,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER)};
            }
      //  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE
        Cursor phoneCur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, params, null);
      /* */



        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        if ( (null == phoneCur) ) {
            createContact(name, phone);
        } else {
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(where, params)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, type)
                    .build());

        }

        phoneCur.close();
        try {
            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```